# I have broken my PATH on bash_profile and nothing works, can't even launch Jupyter notebook

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook, filepath

Here's the response I keep getting whenever I try to launch Jupyter notebook:

```
Users-MacBook:~ user$ jupyter notebook
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

And these are the current content of my .bash_profile:

```
# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/user/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"  
export PATH
export PATH
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/user/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/user/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base

    else
        \export PATH="/Users/user/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Am really frustrated by it. Can I rewrite the bash_profile again or could I just download the `.bash_profile` somewhere; that means I would have to copy it from someone. I've not found anything anywhere.

Comment: it's really unclear what the problem is. Can you do `printf "%q\n" "$PATH"` and `echo "$__conda_setup"`and post the results? You can set a very basic valid PATH with `PATH=$(getconf PATH)` to get yourself up with the basic utilities.

Comment: Users-MacBook:~ user$ printf "%q\n" "$PATH"
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin

Users-MacBook:~ user$ echo "$__conda_setup"

Those are the outputs. But i tried starting up jupyter again and same response.

Comment: I think you should remove the `export PATH` lines: I suspect the `if [ $? eq 0 ]` is supposed to be testing the result of the conda setup command, not the result of the export command.

Comment: Thanks a million glenn jackman. Now my terminal says bash_profile doesn't exist. But what happens if i just get rid of anaconda and reinstall it, would the problem go?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your .bash_profile to something else so it won't mess with your console. To remove it use the full path in command, for example

```
/bin/mv ~/.bash_profile ~/bad_bash_profile
```

Then your next new session will start with whatever is default for all users and you can check what's wrong and fix it.

If you want more info on what's wrong, please post the contents of your `$PATH` variable as commented by glenn jackman.